# Array with large number of elements sort only largest n elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array containing a big number of elements—more than 2,000,000. I need to obtain the highest (or lowest) ranking 300 elements. So whenever I reach the first highest (or lowest) 300 elements of the array, return them. Currently [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is used for the whole array, then the highest (or lowest) ranking elements are returned.

e.g.: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` I want to obtain the highest 3 elements; I need: `{9,8,7}`

Any suggestions on this one?

**EDIT**

Best resource found so far, containing a research/comparison of different solutions:

http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/selecting-top-k-items-from-a-list-efficiently-in-java-groovy/

Source code for the article:

https://github.com/mpollmeier/Selection-Algorithms

Comment: check the other [sort methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: You only want to sort the first 300 elements? Or do you only want the 300 highest/lowest?

Comment: There is `Arrays#sort(Object[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex)`. Read the javadoc and the methods available on the classes/library you're using.

Comment: @Rossiar the 300 highest/lowest

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I read the javadoc, just wrong explanation from my side...I actually need just the top N highest elements of the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use partial `heapsort`. Construct a `minheap` having `1st 300` elements.

Then as you traverse the array further, check whether the current element is greater than the root element of the heap. If it is greater, then delete the root element and add this new element.

After you finish with the entire array, your `minHeap` will have the largest 300 elements.

Extract the root element one by one. The elements will pop out in ascending order.

**Note: The heap will always contain k(300) elements irrespective of the value of N, so heap operations shall be O(logk) in this case.**

**Hence order of complexity of this algorithm is `O(Nlogk)` where N is the size of array**.

**Space Complexity - O(k)**

EDIT:
If you want the lowest 300 elements, then similar algorithm can be followed using a maxheap instead of minheap.

Comment: it's `n log n` i reckon, not `n`; space is `n` because you can sort in place

Comment: @guido The minHeap only has 300 elements. So heap operations in this case is constant time.

Comment: you need to look at the worst case, which is n log n; insertion in an heap is log n

Comment: @guido Why do you say it is nlogn? Insertion in a heap of constant size is constant.

Comment: So if the heap becomes 1k or 10k or 100k or 1m constant size every operation will be constant too?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal you have to scan n elements; potentially you need to insert each of them in the queue, each insertion is log n

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza By constant, I mean not increasing with N, the size of the array. The operation shall be Nlogk if you consider k is also veriable. I have edited my answer.

Comment: And I'm asking if your heap is 1m constant size, all the operations will be O(1)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, IMO asymptotically, the operations shall be O(1) if the heap size constant and is not increasing with N. Am I wrong?

Comment: The fact you know the value of N doesn't mean the operations would become O(1) instantly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm sorry I genuinely can't see where I am wrong. I am not saying you know the value of N (the size of array). But you know the number of top elements that you want (300 or k). Since the size of heap is always k (not N), the operations shall be log(k) or constant if k is constant.

Comment: This answer is correct. The confusion in the comments appears to be terminology. If the list has `n` items and you want to select `k` of them (i.e. `n=2,000,000` and `k=300` as in the question), then the complexity is `O(n log k)`. The heap contains `k` items, and in the worst case you have to do `n` insertions (and `n-k` removals). Insertion is `O(log k)`, and you have to do it `n` times. Thus, `O(n log k)`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? This example sorts the top 4 elements in the array:

```
    double[] arr = new double[]{1.0,4.0,2.0,8.0,3.0,6.0,7.0,5.0};

    int nth = 4; //e.g. - sort the top 4 numbers
    Arrays.sort(arr,arr.length-nth-1,arr.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [(T[], int, int, java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-int-int-java.util.Comparator-), this will sort the given array (`T[]`) in the range specified, only the elements from the first `int arg` to the second `int arg`. The comparator is optional.

Comment: The OP does not want to sort the first 300 elements in the array, he wants to obtain the largest 300 elements.